# Java path to follow

Tags: java

I finished reading tutorials on Java and doing the sample exercises and I am ready to really get into coding Java, the only problem is I am a bit confused as to what I should do now. What path should I take at this point ? Should I join and start contributing to an open source project ? What suggestions would you give ? I'm not actually interested in something particular so anything will do.

For the more advanced programmers, try to put yourself in my position. What would you do now?

Comment: This question is belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn Java from scratch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356137/how-to-learn-java-from-scratch)

Answer (score 5):

Contribution to OSS is definitively a good way to consider at some point, but I don't think that would be an easy task for someone who just started doing sample exercises.

For contributing to OSS, I suppose you would have to consider much more then a programming language, including:

- SCMs - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control,

  - File comparison is related - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_comparison
- Software design patterns - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science),
- Software testing - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing,
- Get familiar with Java libraries such as:

  - Apache Commons - http://commons.apache.org/,
  - Hibernate - http://www.hibernate.org/,
  - Spring Framework - http://www.springsource.org/
- Documenting - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Depending on the project you would like to get involved with, it would probably be wise to familiarize with some of these:

- JDBC - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity
- JMS - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service
- Swing - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)
- JNDI - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface
- JMX - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions

As you can see, it's a lot, so depending on what you want and what level you are at right now, I suppose it would be good for you to stick with some of the programming exercises such as:

- Working on PLEAC Java - http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_java/index.html

  - You may even be able to contribute to PLEAC
- RubyQuiz - http://www.rubyquiz.com

  - Not Java, but problems are rather general, you can try solving them in Java
- CodingBat - http://codingbat.com/java

  - Has some nice problems
- Alioth - http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/

  - Very benchmark oriented, but can be interesting. Look at specific problems (e.g. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/performance.php?test=fasta#about) to see what is needed

When you pass through some of these and feel confident you can continue, I suggest learning some of the libraries, such as Spring.

Hope this helps. Most importantly - note there's always something you can do, whatever you do is better then not doing anything. It's going to keep you motivated and involved in things that you need to know. So learn, learn, learn... Best luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd try to build some kind of data structure like a linked list or something of that nature. It causes you to understand the fundamentals of java and gives you a better understanding of the structure that you make also. Check out one of my old school labs to have some direction. http://www.mediafire.com/?dq1lmshdzage8xo
Try this for implementation example.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_List